# FiddlerCore to capture HTTP & HTTPS in Firefox

Tags: c#, proxy, fiddlercore

I'm researching how I can best monitor HTTP & HTTPS traffic. The application needs to know the full url. I set up the FiddlerApplication as described below:

```
void FiddlerApplication_AfterSessionComplete(Session session)
{
   Console.WriteLine("=== DETECTED: {0}", session.fullUrl);
}

void StartFiddler()
{
   Console.WriteLine("== STARTING FIDDLER");

   if (!FiddlerApplication.IsStarted()) {
      FiddlerApplication.AfterSessionComplete += FiddlerApplication_AfterSessionComplete;
      FiddlerApplication.Startup(8888, true, true, true);
   }
}
```

I do have some questions...

1. This only seems to work when I launch my application as administrator. After the maiden run in administrator, the follow up runs can be done unelevated. Is this intended behaviour?
2. When launching FireFox (for example), users can change the network settings and bypass the proxy set up by Fiddler. Is there a way around this (e.g. can I programatically force FireFox and other applications to go through the proxy)?

Comment: What do you mean "only seems to work"? What happens when you run it unelevated? Are your users in an Active Directory domain?

Comment: When uneleveated: nothing is being captured then. Not all users are in AD, some are. But they all have admin rights on their own machines. I get no output when I haven't launched it as admin first. After I can launch it as normal user though and it generates output, the first time it's needed...